# temporary setting the path in an "init" file

Tags: ubuntu, xterm, path

I have an "init" file that reads

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/morph_numsys/software/bin
```

by which I'd just like to set the path to that folder for only this bash session. However, when I execute the script, `sh init`, it still doesn't recognize the path. However, if I just say `export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/morph_numsys/software/bin`, then it works fine. Any ideas how I can do this?

I'm on ubuntu and xterm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say "for only this bash session", I assume you mean the bash session that is calling the script.

When you execute your script, it gets a new shell environment.  Thus when you export variables, you are exporting it to the new shell environment and not its parent environment.  As far as I know, there is no way to access the parent environment.  However, since you are using bash, there may be a few solutions:

**Use `source`**

Rather than execute the script like this: `/path/to/init.sh` do `source /path/to/init.sh`

From the [bash man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/bash.1.html):

> source filename [arguments]
>
> Read and execute commands from filename in the current shell environment and return the exit status of the last command executed from filename.

**Make your script a shell function and put it in .bashrc**

Another option is to make init a function and put it in .bashrc like this:

```
function init {
    export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/morph_numsys/software/bin
}
```

Then from the terminal you can just run `init`.